# Coldfusion Database insertion changing long numeric value to scientific Notation

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, floating-point

I am trying to update my data base with an input value, the data is being passed to an update coldfusion file through JSON as such: `customValue:"6436534653465346347734653465346"`. The insert/update queries should take this value and just simply insert it into the Database using a `<cfqueryparam>` tag: `<cfqueryparam value="#VARNETJSONInput.customValue#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">`.

However for some reason that i cant understand its being inserted into my MySQL DB as `6.43653465347E+030`. Ive tried using tostring() inside the value to force the insert as a string but it will still convert it to scientific notation. I have to use `cf_sql_varchar` becuase this input can take both numbers and alphabets.

The data base column is type: `varchar (utf8 utf8_general_ci, length: 255)`

Is there a way to force this to insert correctly or possible converting the formula to a long number using coldfusion tags?

```
<cfif getcurrentother.RecordCount GT 0>
            <cfquery name="updateCustom" datasource="#OLMSdatasourceWrite#" result="res_updateCustom">
                UPDATE OLMS_Data_LRSS_CustomSelect
                SET OLMS_LRSS_CustomFieldSelect_Content = #VARNETJSONInput.customValue#
                WHERE OLMS_LRequestSubSet_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#VARNETJSONInput.LRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"> AND
                    OLMS_AccountCustomField_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#VARNETJSONInput.customId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
            </cfquery>
        <cfelse>
            <cfquery name="insertCustom" datasource="#OLMSdatasourceWrite#" result="res_updateCustom">
                INSERT INTO OLMS_Data_LRSS_CustomSelect(OLMS_AccountCustomField_ID, OLMS_LRequestSubSet_ID, OLMS_LRSS_CustomFieldSelect_Content)
                VALUES
                (
                    <cfqueryparam value="#VARNETJSONInput.customId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                    ,<cfqueryparam value="#VARNETJSONInput.LRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                    ,#VARNETJSONInput.customValue#
                );
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>
```

Comment: What kind of length of your column "varchar (utf8 utf8_general_ci)"?

Comment: 255 is the length of the column

Comment: Maybe value changed before insertion? Did you run your sql query as command without coldfusion?

Comment: yes ive even removed the cfqueryparam and its still doing it

Comment: Could you give me full plain sql statement?

Comment: added to the main question

Comment: @MVG1984 ive narrowed down the issue more. The issue is upon `<cfset VARNETJSONdeS = deserializeJSON(varnetJSON)>` The vlaue goes in as a long numbers and comes out as a formula?

Comment: In the code above, there are no single quotes around `#VARNETJSONInput.customValue#` which would indicate a number.

Comment: `6.43653465347E+030` is, of course, no formula. It's a correct representation of a 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point number value. It looks like CF is gratuitously recognizing that your string of digits is some kind of a number, and converting it to floating point and back before putting it into the dbms.  You might try putting appending a space to the number string before handing it to CF to put into MySQL.

Comment: `<codger_mode>` People can get jobs handling other peoples' data without being able to recognize floating point numbers?  Really? It's half a century now they've worked that way. `</codger_mode>`

Comment: @O.Jones sorry i miss typed here, your right its not a formula its Scientific Notation. This isnt a problem with how im handling the data actually, this is a problem with coldfusion and how it deserializedJSON :) See:

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4106369

Comment: @O.Jones also i cant append a space to the end of the number as then it wont read the correct value. Thats a "hacky" way of getting around this bug, and a terrible coding practice. <codger _mode>People actually get jobs and instead of correcting a bug they just hack fix it</codger _mode>

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing numbers as strings, you can always send a string.

```
<cfqueryparam 
value="#numberFormat(VARNETJSONInput.customValue, '9999999999999999999999999999')#" 
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Just make sure you have enough 9s.

Comment: Definitely a good attempt but that wont work because the input also takes alphabets and characters :/

Comment: You can perform some conditional logic as to whether or not the string is numeric, or contains certain characters, etc,.

Comment: Ill give it a shot and see what i can do with this. im actually curious to see if `numberFormat` is smart enough to convert scientific notation!

Comment: So `numberFormat` isnt smart enough to take a deserializedJSON object's value and if its numeric convert a scientific notional value to a normal integer sadly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with coldfusion and they have been made aware of it:

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4106369